# Must I specify endding tag with jquery.append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am studying somebody else jquery script, and I noticed he is opening a tag without closing it, but it also seems that browsers does not care (Not yet tested with IE)

it is written :

```
$('#mydiv').append('<ul>')
```

But there is nowhere a

```
.append('</ul>')
```

The script does not close the list, but browsers do it automatically (I just did an 'inspect element' in the browser).

Is that a 'legal' behavior, or one should always close a tag in a javascript autogenerated content ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it properly, you *should* be appending:

```
$('#mydiv').append('<ul></ul>')
```

Yes browsers will handle it (specifically the `.innerHTML` implementation handles it, **not** jQuery), at least the major ones, but why not be safe in all cases and use valid markup?

```
$('#mydiv').append('<ul>')
```

...**still** calls `.innerHTML`, not `createElement`, only in `$('<ul>')` is [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement) called.  As I said originally, the browser handles it with [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), *not* jQuery and *not* [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement) (which doesn't take syntax like this anyway).
[You can see test/play with what I mean here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/w7B26/)

Comment: Since I saw `document.createElement` being used for `init`, I figured it would just do the same in `append`, e.g. apply some regex to get the actual tag name and call `createElement`. Turns out its a bit more tricky than that, probably for efficiency

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you should.

Long answer that lead to the short answer:

When you say `.append('<ul>')`,
or even `.append('<ul></ul')`, behind the scenes jQuery calls [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement) and the browser knows what to do.

It's not like jQuery actually puts that string of HTML anywhere, but rather parses it and creates the necessary DOM elements

UPDATE-
As Nick pointed out, this might not always be the case. Relevant source: [`init`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=init)
If you pass it just `ul`, it just calls `createElement`. If the html string is more complicated, it will go into [`buildFragment`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=_buildFragment) which is more complicated than that.

Based on this, I would say the best/fastest way to create a single element thru jQuery, is to do something like

```
$('<ul>').appendTo($target);
```

UPDATE 2-
So apparently jQuery only calls `createElement` in some methods, but `append` ends up calling [`clean`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery.clean) which has a regex that closes tags. So either way, you're safe, jQuery saves you as usual.
Relevant source:

```
...

} else if ( typeof elem === "string" ) {
  // Fix "XHTML"-style tags in all browsers
  elem = elem.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

  ...
```

UPDATE 3- So it turns out jQuery doens't fix anything for you when you call `append`, and it just injects the string into a temporary `div` element. Seems like most browsers know how to deal with the HTML even if not closed properly, but to be save it's probably best to close it yourself! Or if you're feeling lazy, do something like `.append($('<ul>'))` which doesn't use innerHTML

Comment: "It's not like jQuery actually puts that string of HTML anywhere"...that's **exactly** what it does, it creates a document fragment then sets the HTML given what was provided.  This answer is not at allmcorrect, it's `innerHTML` handling this, **not** jQuery or `createElement`.

Comment: Hmm.. after some more careful inspection of the jQuery source, it seems like it uses both methods, depending where. E.g. if you pass it just 'ul', it will just create that element: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=init

Comment: @Infinity - Yes, in that specfic case (but **not** with `.append()`, you're looking at code that handles `$('<ul>')`).  The rest of your answer is incorrect as well, `.append('<ul></ul')` isn't handled by jQuery, it's handled by `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Did some more digging.. updated my answer. Good to know all this

Comment: @Infinity - Again it's still wrong, that only closes certain self-closing (in XHTML) tags, look at the regex: `rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([\w:]+)[^>]*)\/>/ig,`.  Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RqVtt/

Comment: @Nick, hmmm. I wonder when that regex is actually useful, it doesn't seem to do anything: http://jsfiddle.net/QheSW/1/